# JAXB-ElipseLink: @XmlJavaTypeAdapter and the type-attribute

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am using @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to marshal fields of type Map to XML. This results in EclipseLink-MOXy creating an `xsi:type="<myValueType>"`-attribute on the output xml-element.
Upon validation the referenced type can of course not be found.

Is there any way of suppressing the generation of this attribute?

PS: An XmlAdapter-tag would be handy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the type-attribute had nothing to do with the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation.
It was caused by the fact, that the Map's elements were of a derived type and MOXy correctly marshalled their type to a type-attribute.

Using `<xml-element-ref>` instead of `<xml-element>` solved the issue.